# using nginx' lua to validate GitHub webhooks and delete cron-lock-file

Tags: json, nginx, github, lua, webhooks

## What I have:

- GNU/Linux host
- nginx is up and running
- there is a cron-job scheduled to run immediately after a specific file has been removed (similar to run-crons)
- GitHub sends a webhook when someone pushes to a repository

## What I want:

I do now want to run either lua or anything comparable to parse GitHub's request and validate it and then delete a file (if the request was valid of course).

Preferably all of this should happen without the hassle to maintain an additional PHP installation as there is currently none, or the need to use fcgiwrap or similar.

## Template:

On the nginx side I have something equivalent to

```
location /deploy {
    # execute lua (or equivalent) here
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To read json body of GH webhook you nead use [JSON4Lua](http://json.luaforge.net/) lib, and to validate HMAC signature use [luacrypto](http://mkottman.github.io/luacrypto/).

#### Preconfigure

Install required modules

```
$ sudo luarocks install JSON4Lua
$ sudo luarocks install luacrypto
```

In Nginx define location for deploy

```
  location /deploy {
    client_body_buffer_size 3M;
    client_max_body_size  3M;

    content_by_lua_file /path/to/handler.lua;
  }
```

The `max_body_size` and `body_buffer_size` should be equal to prevent error

> request body in temp file not supported

https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/issues/521

---

#### Process webhook

Get request payload data and check is correct

```
ngx.req.read_body()
local data = ngx.req.get_body_data()

if not data then
    ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "failed to get request body")
    return ngx.exit (ngx.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST)
end
```

Verify GH signature with use luacrypto

```
local function verify_signature (hub_sign, data)
    local sign = 'sha1=' .. crypto.hmac.digest('sha1', data, secret)
    -- this is simple comparison, but it's better to use a constant time comparison
    return hub_sign == sign
end

-- validate GH signature
if not verify_signature(headers['X-Hub-Signature'], data) then
    ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "wrong webhook signature")
    return ngx.exit (ngx.HTTP_FORBIDDEN)
end
```

Parse data as json and check is master branch, for deploy

```
data = json.decode(data)
-- on master branch
if data['ref'] ~= branch then
    ngx.say("Skip branch ", data['ref'])
    return ngx.exit (ngx.HTTP_OK)
end
```

If all correct, call deploy function

```
local function deploy ()
    -- run command for deploy
    local handle = io.popen("cd /path/to/repo && sudo -u username git pull")
    local result = handle:read("*a")
    handle:close()

    ngx.say (result)
    return ngx.exit (ngx.HTTP_OK)
end
```

---

#### Example

Example constant time string compare

```
local function const_eq (a, b)
    -- Check is string equals, constant time exec
    getmetatable('').__index = function (str, i)
        return string.sub(str, i, i)
    end

    local diff = string.len(a) == string.len(b)
    for i = 1, math.min(string.len(a), string.len(b)) do
        diff = (a[i] == b[i]) and diff
    end
    return diff
end
```

A complete example of how I use it in github gist  https://gist.github.com/Samael500/5dbdf6d55838f841a08eb7847ad1c926

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not implement verification for GitHub's hooks and assumes you have the lua extension and the cjson module installed:

```
location = /location {
    default_type 'text/plain';

    content_by_lua_block {
        local cjson = require "cjson.safe"
        ngx.req.read_body()
        local data = ngx.req.get_body_data()

        if
            data
        then
            local obj = cjson.decode(data)

            if
                # checksum checking should go here
                (obj and obj.repository and obj.repository.full_name) == "user/reponame"
            then
                local file = io.open("<your file>","w")

                if
                    file
                then
                    file:close()

                    ngx.say("success")
                else
                    ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                end
            else
                ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED)
            end
        else
            ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_NOT_ALLOWED)
        end
    }
}
```